# How can i put image in Three.js texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I am trying to put a texture in a Three.js object, but when I apply the image the object goes all black. Some alerts are shown on code but no errors. Image above show results. Some advice, please?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Meu Primeiro WebGL</title>
    <style type="text/css">canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%}</style>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>
<body>
<script src="three.js"></script>


<script>
       var scene = new THREE.Scene();
       var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            //primeiro cubo
            var cubegeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5,0.45,5);
            var cubematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: false, color: 0x0033FF});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubegeometry, cubematerial);



            //segundo objeto 
            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('wood.jpg');
            var cbmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: texture});
            var cbgeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5.05,0.5,3.75);

            var cb = new THREE.Mesh(cbgeometry, cbmaterial);



            scene.add(cube);
            scene.add(cb);
            camera.position.z = 6

            var render = function(){
                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                cube.rotation.y += 0.02;
                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.z += 0.00;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add a light into the scene? If not, phongmaterial wil be rendered in black, just like a object in a completely dark room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any light in the scene, that's probably the problem. Add at least some ambient light. For example:

```
var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x555555 );
scene.add( ambient );
```